# SvelteKit: cookies.set() In Form Action Not Working

Tags: javascript, cookies, jwt, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to implement JWT-based user sessions with SvelteKit, and have mostly been following the explanation for form actions given on their website: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions

+page.svelte

```js
<form method="POST" action="?/signIn">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

+page.server.svelte

```js
import { fail, redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import { signIn } from "$lib/server/database";

export const actions = {
  signIn: async ({ cookies, request }) => {
    const data = await request.formData();

    const name = data.get("name");
    const password = data.get("password");

    if (!name || !password) {
      return fail(400);
    }

    try {
      cookies.set("jwt", await signIn(name, password));
    } catch (error) {
      return fail(400);
    }

    throw redirect(303, "/");
  },
};
```

I have tested my `signIn` method which I import and use here, and it does return a token when called with the correct credentials. So far, so good. However, I noticed that I don't see any cookies in my developer tools. It seems like the `cookies.set()` call simply does nothing. I'd like to set the returned JWT as a cookie so that I can authenticate my users, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting the cookie for the root path? `cookies.set("jwt", await signIn(name, password), { path: "/" });`

Comment: I just tried that, there are still no cookies in sight.

Comment: Shoot, that's frustrating. Have you tried [cloning the `realworld` example](https://github.com/sveltejs/realworld/blob/master/src/routes/login/%2Bpage.server.js) and checked if that sets a cookie for you? If it does, you could compare that code to yours. If it does not, maybe you have disabled cookies in your browser in some way.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped me find the problem: Apparently, I just can't set cookies in this browser. Which confuses me, because I just did today, but that was with another framework. But the realworld example also doesn't work for me, so it's my browser. I'm just going to try and find the setting for that and change it.

Comment: You might want to specify a cookie options object in your `cookies.set` call. By default, SvelteKit sets the `httpOnly` and `secure` flags to `true` (`secure` is set to `false` if running on `localhost`) which might interfere with your ability to transmit to, and read the cookie back on the client side. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-cookies.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but these options shouldn't prevent the cookie from being _set_ in the first place, right? Because I'm just using my dev tools to check for the cookie, and it's simply not there. Even with these options set, it should show up, shouldn't it?

Comment: I tried around a little, and noticed that while the cookies are not set when I use Safari (which is my normal browser), they are set when using Chrome. However, on my phone, Chrome doesn't work, Safari doesn't work, and Firefox also doesn't work. So I get the impression that this `cookies.set` method doesn't work in most browsers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anybody else has this problem: While the cookie was set as it was supposed to when using Chrome, it wasn't in Safari. I solved this by setting the `secure` option to false, even though the SvelteKit docs state that this is done automatically on localhost.

Comment: I had this problem too, but in Firefox on Linux.